# Add a tool in Backpack of the player by scripting

Tags: lua, roblox

i am trying to make a farming game and making a shop in that game. As i click the shop button it appears a window for Shopping tools but when i click the tool it is not moving to my Backpack

this is my code to buy items:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ToolEvent.LampEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    if player.leaderstats.cash.Value >= 100 then
        player.leaderstats.cash.Value = player.leaderstats.cash.Value - 100
        local clone = game.ServerStorage.Tools.Lamp:Clone()
        clone.parent = player.StarterGear
        end
end)

game.ReplicatedStorage.ToolEvent.PickaxeEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    if player.leaderstats.cash.Value >= 150 then
        player.leaderstats.cash.Value = player.leaderstats.cash.Value - 150
        local clone = game.ServerStorage.Tools.Pickaxe:Clone()
        clone.parent = player.StarterGear
    end
end)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript to me.

Comment: Is this a roblox mod? https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent --- I believe it is, so I've updated the language tag to be Lua.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its Instance.Parent, not Instance.parent

I'm no Roblox expert.
I presume setting the Parent property will somehow create a reference in the parent instance so it is not garbage collected once your local `clone` runs out of scope.

So fixing the typo probably solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `clone.parent`, the `parent` needs capital letter: `clone.Parent` and it's recommended to get the services using a builtin function: `game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')` and `game:GetService('ServerStorage')`

Answer (score 0):

You should move the cloned item to the player's Backpack, not StarterGear, because the backpack is where tools are stored for the player to interact with. So instead of: `clone.parent = player.StarterGear` do `clone.Parent = player.Backpack`

Answer (score 0):

In line 5 of your script, you cloned the tool in the startergear. But it should be the player's backpack. Try this.

```
clone.Parent = player.BackPack
```